# AngularJS - How to use a service from within a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get my head around scopes and after dredging through a number of blogs, stack overflow answers and the docs I am still stuck.

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('alphabet', function () {
    data = [
      'c', 
      'b',
      'a'
    ];

    return {
      get : function () {
        return data;
      },
      set : function (val) {
        data.push(val);
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('AlphaCtrl', function (alphabet) {
    this.alphabet = alphabet;
  })
  .directive('sortableTable', function () {
    return {
      scope : {
         "param" : '@'
      },

      link : function (scope) {
        console.log(scope.param);
      }
    };
  })
;
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="AlphaCtrl as alpha">
    <table sortable-table param="{{alpha.alphabet}}">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I would like to do is be able to access a service/factory that's being used in an outer controller from within a directive. So for example when I handle a click event I can add items to the data. That seems to be a good way of keeping things decoupled but I am open to suggestions there.

The problem at hand is that 'param' is undefined. I've also tried using '&' but that's not doing anything for me. Could someone put me on the path to Angular righteousness?

Comment: Yes it did - thank you. Things would work out just fine had I just used alpha.alphabet instead of {{alpha.alphabet}} I think. See comment on your answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would inject the service directly into the directive:

```
.directive('sortableTable', function (alphabet) {
   return {
     scope : {},

     link : function (scope) {
       console.log(alphabet);
     }
   };
})
```

This is indeed a good way of keeping things decoupled, if this is a directive that is used across controllers and views.

---

**Edit for a bit more complex solution:** It *is* possible to do it by injecting the service into the scope of the directive, though I would not recommend it if you don't need to switch services on the fly, since the method above is easier. I could see some use cases though, if you would want to input a different service (with the same get/set structure) in another controller for example. Here's how you could do it via scope:

```
.controller('myController', function($scope, alphabet) {
    $scope.alphabet = alphabet;
})
.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            service: '='
        },
        template: '<div ng-bind="service.get()"></div>'
    }
})
```

And in the template:

```
<div data-my-directive service="alphabet"></div>
```

The trick here is using `service: '='` as this creates a two-way binding between the scope-variable in the controller (which is bound to the service) and the scope-variable in the directive. http://jsfiddle.net/vt52bauu/2/

Comment: Thanks. I accept the answer above. The second part is most relevant for me as I might want to inject different services into the directive. Would be nice to know why this isn't optimal. The source of my confusion came from  me misreading the documentation and using {{ }} around the service name.

Comment: What I meant, is that it's not optimal if you're always going to inject the same service into the directive (which may be what most people want). Then I would recommend the top version, as it should offer less confusion. If you're going to use different services depending on context, then the bottom one is for you. So I guess it's wrong to say that it's less optimal in your case :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the get/set is going to work the way you are expecting in an Angular factory.

```
this.alphabet = alphabet.get();
```

Comment: You're correct - I made a mistake there. Ultimately I got rid of the getter and setter methods. They were there as a convenience for having a place firing off change events from.